# How to continue recording even after pressing the home button?

Tags: android, audio-recording

I'm programming an `Android` application (I'm using `Android Studio`).

I start the recording with the following code (this is just a fragment):

```
public void start() {
    int minBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE, CHANNELS, AUDIO_ENCODING);
    audioRecord = new AudioRecord(
            MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            SAMPLE_RATE, CHANNELS, AUDIO_ENCODING,
            minBufferSize
    );
    audioRecord.startRecording();
    recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            readAudioData();
        }
    }, "AudioRecorder Thread");
    recordingThread.start();
}
```

I want, when I press the home button, the application continues recording. Right now, when I press the home button, the recording stops.

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can to create a service and you can start the service when you want to record audio it works even you press home button.

You can start service by

```
startService(new Intent(YourActivity,Service.class));
```

and can call that method `onStartCommand()`
and can stop service by this

```
stopService(new Intent(YourActivity,Service.class));
```

or by `stopself();`